# $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_j=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, power-series

This is an exercise from mathematical analysis by zorich:

> After considering the product of the series
> $(a_0 + a_1 + \cdots )(b_0 +b_1+\cdots ) = (c_0 + c_1+\cdots )$ ,
> where $c_n = a_0b_n + a_1b_{n-1} + \cdots +  a_{n-1}b_1 + a_nb_0$, and using Proposition 1, show that if the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n , \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n,$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n$ converge respectively to $A, B$, and $C$,
> then $A\cdot B = C$.

The proposition 1 is a corollary of Abel's second theorem:

> [proposition 1] If a power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n(z - z_0)^n
>  $converges at a point $\zeta$, it  converges uniformly on the closed interval $[z_0,\zeta]$ from $z_0$ to $\zeta$, and the sum
> of the series is continuous on that interval.

My solution:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_{i-1}x^{i}\sum_{j=1}^Nb_{j-1}x^{j}-\sum_{k=1}^{N}c_{k-1}x^{k}=x^N\sum_{l=1}^Nd_lx^l$$
Since $|a_i|\leq M,|b_j|\leq L$ is bounded, $|d_l|\leq 2NML=NC$.

For a fixed $x< 1$, $|x^N\sum_{l=1}^Nd_l x^l|\leq x^{N+1}N^2C\to 0$, as $N\to \infty$. Hence $$\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_{i-1} x^{i}\cdot\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^N b_{j-1}x^{j}=\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{N}c_{k-1} x^{k}$$

Use the proposition 1 to pass to the limit $x\to 1$ and we get  $AB=C$.

**I don't know if the solution above is correct, so feel free to point out some mistakes or give any advice or another solution.**

Comment: We have already know both series converges on x=1, then the proposition works.

Comment: @LEY : "Converges on $x = 1$" is not enough room to take a limit approaching $1$.  You need an open interval of convergence around $1$ for a two-sided limit or a half-open interval for either one-sided limit.

Comment: Converges on point 1, then uniformly convergent on interval[0,1], hence $\sum c_nx^n$ is continuous at 1, and limiting passage can be commuted so we can move the $\lim over \sum$.

Comment: This seems right to me. Just being boring, I believe you will have $|d_l|\leq 2 N M L$.

Comment: Seems $NML$ is enough because there are at most N item for every $l$?

Comment: Please avoid math-only titles. See [Guidelines for good use of MathJax in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/888233) for more information.